# bdist_wheel: which files included by default?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

Does anyone know which files are included by default and which one I need to define via `package_data` keyword, if I create a python package using `python setup.py bdist_wheel`?

The only thing I could found until now is just about [license files](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#including-license-files-in-the-generated-wheel-file).

Comment: I am sure [the doc for `sdist`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute) provides the list of files included by default for every other distribution types.

Comment: Unfortunately the docu just talks about how it works for `sdist`. But `bdist_wheel` is quite different, because it doesn't support `MANIFEST.in` and my linked example about the license file also different. So I guess there are more differences.